# I want to study human brain and consciousness. Should i study neuroscience or neuro-physics?

Tags: advisor, career-path, physics, biology, neuroscience

I am a high school student and my dream is to study about human brain and consciousness. Which subject should I study in university, neuroscience or neuro-physics (which is a branch of biophysics)?

Comment: I guess it depends on what exactly you want to study. You may even want to study psychology or philosophy.

Comment: @MarkSapir I want to study brain and consciousness from the perspective of natural science. According to my understanding, psychology is a social science and philosophy is the ancient ancestor of all academic disciplines including those that fall under natural science but philosophy itself is not a part of  natural science.

Comment: Still it is not very concrete. Neuroscience includes neurophysics. Are  you interested in a part of neuroscience which is not neurophysics?

Comment: look at the courses offered by those two degrees and you will find your answer. Consciousness is quite a bit higher in the continuum of abstractness than a lot of neuroscience, which in turn sounds higher than neuro-physics. (All are lower / "harder" than philosophy). You might find that you're spending more time than you'd like studying fundamental physical and biological properties of neurons in either course you've suggested, when what you're interested in gets discussed more in psychology or cognitive science degrees. Psychology has but one arm in the social sciences, it is much broader